# native html element input bind to asp.net event behind code

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

hello guys im using a normal element "input text" now what im trying to do is bind my "input text" into an event handler under asp.net behind code method sample

normal scenario using asp.net element

aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtasptext" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtasptext" ></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void txtasptext(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "hello asp element";
    }
```

but my goal is using normal element text, see below

aspx

```
<input type="text" id="txtnormaltext" runat="server" />
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void txtnormaltext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string name = "hello normal element";
}
```

need some help thanks and happy new year everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript and AJAX call a web service:

```
<script>
function doSomething()
{
var params = $('#txtnormal').val();
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AjaxHandler.asmx/DoSomethingMethod",
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (e) { alert('exception:' + e); }
      });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtnormaltext" onchange="doSomething()" />
```

AjaxHandler.asmx Web Service:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DoSomethingMethod(string inputText)
{
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this HTML control you need to find it from your page_load and bind methods to it.

```
 HtmlGenericControl mytxtbox =(HtmlGenericControl) FindControlRecursive(pnl, "textboxID");
 mytxtbox.Attributes.Add("textbox_event_name", "Your_C#_Function");
```

View the FindControlRecursive function from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263086/finding-an-htmlgenericcontrol%20Here)